Get geometry position
maybe this is a noob question, but I just cannot find an answer anywhere.
All I want to do is get the position of a geometry, because I need to generate a curve line with the starting point corresponding to the position of that generated geometry.
My situation is shown in the following image:

I've seen the Object info node, but it does not accept a geometry as input. I've also tried with the Capture Attribute and the Sample Index, both didn't work. Maybe I am doing something wrong?
EDIT:
As suggested by user @Chris, I've edited the question to show the node tree... The overall is very complex, so I cleaned up a bit.
I have this node group, called "nodo":

The output of this group is treated as shown below, and that's where I need to operate:

The socket "Terminale" in the Object Info node is an empty.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but it's the input node Position that will give you position of your geometry (position of vertex/edge/face/instance/... depending on context).

Thank you for your answer @Lutzi, I've edited the question in order to better describe what I need

What position are you trying to get exactly ? What is your geometry ?

i recommend posting your whole node tree so we know what you are talking about. And of course you should show us your capture attribute/sample index - try, because this "should" work.  Or you provide your blend file, so that we can definitely help you quickly without asking in comments.

@Chris the overall node three is very complex, anyway I'll clean it up a bit and post just the branch where I need to operate. Thank you.

Tried again with the Sample Index node, this time worked.
Maybe I had no luck in my previous attempts because of wrong input parameters.

